# split faces for UVs

Tags: uv

I'm starting with blender, and I'd like to know how can I move some UV vertex without messing with the others.

Under Maya there was a 'cut Uv shell' tool, that allow that, but I cannot find the same thing in blender

Comment: You can pin UV vertices from the UV menu.  Be sure to read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Thanks again, it was exactly what I was looking for.